# Non-capturing group reg-ex in Sublime Text not working

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

[image]
I'm trying to remove all lingering spaces between tags. So I try to select them with a regex.

```
<span>        </span>
      ^^^^^^^^
```

My regex is `(?:>) +(?:<)`. I'm trying to exclude the `>` and `<` from the selection with a non-capturing group, but it doesn't seem to be working.

At the moment, these two regexes seem to do the exact same thing:

With non-capturing groups: `(?:>) +(?:<)`

Without non-capturing groups: `> +<`

I think my understanding of regex is not good enough, but I'm not sure. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [non-capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) doesn't capture the subpattern in a group (that you can refer later), however, all that have been matched in a non-capturing group is not excluded from the whole match result.

The way to solve the problem is to use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) that are zero-width assertions. Lookarounds are only tests and are not part of the final result.

for spaces:

```
(?<=>) +(?=<)
```

for all whitespace-characters:

```
(?<=>)\s+(?=<)
```

(An other solution consists to use `> +<` with `><` as replacement string)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of non-capturing groups is to allow you to interact with a set of characters as a group without making it a submatch that you can use in a reference. So you are correct `(?:>) +(?:<)` is equivalent for your purposes to `> +<`.