# regular expression to match src attribute value within a video tag

Tags: regex

```
<video id="video" class="playerVideo" autoplay="1" x-webkit-airplay="allow" src="**matchme.mp4**" type="video/mp4">
```

This is what I have so far:

```
(?<=<video[^<>]+src=")/w*(?<!"[^<>]/video>)
```

I think my problems are stemming from [not being able to use repetition within a lookaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3159524/why-doesnt-finite-repetition-in-lookbehind-work-in-some-flavorsp).
Just to be clear, i want to match the **value** inside the src attribute of a video tag,not including the attribute itself (src="**matchme**").

Comment: That's the place to go: [regular expressions 101](https://www.regex101.com/)

Comment: Use a capturing group. Even better a proper HTML parser.

Comment: @HamZa thanks, also, an html parser is not appropriate in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a better solution, because it works with [PCRE, JS, and Python](https://www.regex101.com/r/pH6aE7/1).

```
<video[^>]+src=\"([^"]+)
```

However, I could not get it to work with Sublime Text 3.
Finally, this worked with sublime:

```
<video[^>]+src=\"\K[^"]+
```

[The `\K` assertion tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23964362/why-cant-you-use-repetition-quantifiers-in-zero-width-look-behind-assertions)

Answer (score 2):

Try this pattern:

```
(?:<video[^>]+src=\")(?<src>[^"]+)
```

the capturing group is "src"

Working examples in:

- [PHP](https://www.regex101.com/r/eA8tQ1/3)
- [JavaScript](https://www.regex101.com/r/eA8tQ1/2)

Comment: in sublime it matched from the beginning video tag (<video), to the end of the source attribute value (src="...)

Comment: I got this to work for JS `(?:<video[^>]+src=\")([^"]+)`, but still none that work in sublime

Comment: apparently you have to use lookarounds with sublime?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24412844/non-capturing-group-reg-ex-in-sublime-text-not-working